# replace each number, a[i] with next higher number on its right side,

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of integers, replace each number, a[i] with next higher number(according to value) on its right side, whose value is closer to a[i] (if not present than keep it as it is.)

for e.g.

input – > 3 7 5

output -> 5 7 5

input –> 3 6 2 6 4 7 1

output-> 4 7 4 7 7 7 1

This question was asked in an interview.

If start from right and insert each element in BST and then finding the closer value in BST but this approach would also be O(n^2) in the worst case.

Is there any optimized approach for this?

Comment: If you use a self-balancing BST, you can easily get to `O(NlogN)`.

Comment: How about storing creating an array with number and index - O(n), sort that with O(nlogn), recreate the array? O(n). That would be n + n + nlogn -> O(nlogn)

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Ummm... you sure recreate can be done in O(n)? I do not really see it. In 5 mins I came up with something that would recreate I think in O(n log n) for average and O(n^2) at worst. Could you please lay it out? I feel stupid but curious =)

Comment: my resulting calculation was nlogn: n for creating a new array with numers and index, nlogn for sorting and the last n for recreating.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a balanced BST for the entire list of numbers. Then, go through the list again, using the tree to find the next larger number. After each item is done, remove it from the tree.

The depth of the tree never increases, so the total complexity is O(n log n) for building the tree in the first place, O(log n) per item for finding the next largest item, and O(log n) for removing the current item. Overall O(n log n) with no fancy data structures.